# Can not assign new property in react , got ` Can't add property xxx, object is not extensible`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to make a dialog component used to submit form.

### Code

```
class SubmitDialog extends React.PureComponent {
  toggleDialog() {
    this.setState({isOpen:!this.state.isOpen})
  }

  handleSubmit() {
    // children need have handleSubmit
    this.props.children.props.handleSubmit()
    this.toggleDialog()
  }

  render(){
    const {children, title } = this.props;

    // I want to pass a button to trigger open this dialog
    let trigger = React.cloneElement(this.props.trigger);
    trigger.onClick = this.toggleDialog;

    return (

      {trigger},
      <Dialog
        open={this.state.isOpen}
        onClose={() => {this.toggleDialog()}}
        className="dialog"
      >
        <DialogHeader>
          <DialogTitle>{title}</DialogTitle>
        </DialogHeader>
        <DialogBody scrollable className="dialog-body">
          {children}
        </DialogBody>
        <DialogFooter className="align-axis">
          <Button raised className="cyan white-text" onClick={()=> { this.toggleDialog() }}>取消</Button>
          <Button raised primary onClick={()=> { this.handleSubmit() }} >提交</Button>
        </DialogFooter>
      </Dialog>
    )
  }

};
```

### Purpose

I want to pass

1. a form with handleSumbit function (children)
2. a clickable element to open this dialog  (trigger)

Because outside component don't know how to open this dialog, I tend to pass the element into dialog, and let dialog pass a onClick funtion to it.
But I found I can't add set property to `this.props.trigger`. I tried to add `React.cloneElement` , but still not work.

Tried `Object.seal` :
[image]

Comment: `Object.seal` will, well, seal the object, after which no property on it can be changed/created/etc.. TypeScript knows this and returns a `Readonly<T>` of your original object, hence why are getting a compile-time error. If TypeScript didn't throw this error, you'd get runtime errors instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
React.cloneElement(this.props.trigger, {
        onClick: this.toggleDialog
});
```

Comment: maybe you need to use this.toggleDialog.bind(this)